# adding animation to canvas wheel using javascript, spinning wheel animation

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to make a simple animation for a wheel, and I'm not sure how to define the animation function of it.

index.html, can be found below, trying to keep the body clean... (no real reson).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

javascript, can be found below or using the jsfiddle link.
I have compose the wheel from 2 main canvas, one is the outterWheel and the other one is the innerWheel which is filled to cover the lines of outterWheel, give the impression of a mechanical wheel.

```js
let buttonDOM = document.createElement('canvas');
buttonDOM.id = 'outterWheel';
buttonDOM.width = 80;
buttonDOM.height = 60;
document.body.appendChild(buttonDOM);
ctx = document.getElementById('outterWheel').getContext('2d');
ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.beginPath();
const smallLines = [ 0, 22.5, 45, 67.5, 90, 112.5, 135, 157.5, 180, 202.5, 225, 247.5, 270, 292.5, 315, 337.5 ];
ctx.fillStyle = "#76D7C4";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 80, 60);
ctx.arc(40, 30, 15, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
for (var angle of smallLines){
    ctx.moveTo(40, 30);
    ctx.lineTo(40 + 17 * Math.cos(angle * Math.PI * 2 / 360), 30 + 17 * Math.sin(angle * Math.PI * 2 / 360));
}
ctx.stroke();
buttonDOM = document.createElement('canvas');
buttonDOM.id = 'innerWheel';
buttonDOM.width = 80;
buttonDOM.height = 60;
document.body.appendChild(buttonDOM);
ctx = document.getElementById('innerWheel').getContext('2d');
ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "#76D7C4";
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 80, 60);
ctx.arc(40, 30, 15, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = "#76D7C4";
ctx.fill();
for (var angle of smallLines){
    ctx.moveTo(40, 30);
    ctx.lineTo(40 + 18 * Math.cos((angle + 11.25) * Math.PI * 2 / 360), 30 + 18 * Math.sin((angle + 11.25) * Math.PI * 2 / 360));
}
ctx.stroke();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nh63c28w/2/

Comment: And how should the animation look like? Do you want to layer both wheels on-top each other and rotate both clockwise?

Comment: yes both wheels, rotate/spin should work. the spinning clock or counter doesn't really affect which one makes it easier :d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you're using two `<canvas>` elements to draw your wheels. I'd recommend using a single instance for creating each wheel initially. With the help of the `canvas.toDataURL()` you can store a snapshot of your canvas' content to a  element and re-use the two images to compose your final animation on the canvas.

To actually draw the animation we can utilize a combination of the `translate()`, `rotate()` and `drawImage()` methods. **translate** will move the context to a specific x & y position, **rotate** will rotate the canvas by a certain amount given in radians and **drawImage** will finally draw the given image at the context's current position.

To change the animation over time - like rotating the wheels - we need to re-trigger the animation function. This is done by the `requestAnimationFrame()` function which calls a given callBack function at the refreshrate of your monitor e.g. 60 times per second on a 60hz display.

For example:

```js
let buttonDOM = document.createElement('canvas');
buttonDOM.id = 'outerWheel';
buttonDOM.width = 80;
buttonDOM.height = 60;
document.body.appendChild(buttonDOM);
ctx = document.getElementById('outerWheel').getContext('2d');
ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.beginPath();
const smallLines = [0, 22.5, 45, 67.5, 90, 112.5, 135, 157.5, 180, 202.5, 225, 247.5, 270, 292.5, 315, 337.5];
ctx.fillStyle = "#76D7C4";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 80, 60);
ctx.arc(40, 30, 15, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
for (var angle of smallLines) {
  ctx.moveTo(40, 30);
  ctx.lineTo(40 + 17 * Math.cos(angle * Math.PI * 2 / 360), 30 + 17 * Math.sin(angle * Math.PI * 2 / 360));
}
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
let outerWheel = new Image();
outerWheel.src = buttonDOM.toDataURL();

ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 80, 60);
ctx.arc(40, 30, 15, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fill();
for (var angle of smallLines) {
  ctx.moveTo(40, 30);
  ctx.lineTo(40 + 18 * Math.cos((angle + 11.25) * Math.PI * 2 / 360), 30 + 18 * Math.sin((angle + 11.25) * Math.PI * 2 / 360));
}
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
let innerWheel = new Image();
innerWheel.src = buttonDOM.toDataURL();
let innerWheelProperties = {
  x: 75,
  y: 100,
  rotation: 0
};
let outerWheelProperties = {
  x: 250,
  y: 100,
  rotation: 0
};
buttonDOM.width = 300;
buttonDOM.height = 200;

function animation() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, buttonDOM.width, buttonDOM.height);
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(innerWheelProperties.x, innerWheelProperties.y);
  ctx.rotate(innerWheelProperties.rotation * Math.PI / 180);
  ctx.drawImage(innerWheel, 0 - innerWheel.width / 2, 0 - innerWheel.height / 2);
  ctx.restore();
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(outerWheelProperties.x, outerWheelProperties.y);
  ctx.rotate(outerWheelProperties.rotation * Math.PI / 180);
  ctx.drawImage(outerWheel, 0 - outerWheel.width / 2, 0 - outerWheel.height / 2);
  ctx.restore();
  outerWheelProperties.rotation++;
  innerWheelProperties.rotation -= 0.5;
  requestAnimationFrame(animation);

}
requestAnimationFrame(animation);
```

Comment: thank you, I can work with those <3 appreciate your quick response mate